Fractional Dehn Twist coefficient of monodromy of rational open book
Given an open book $(S,h)$, the fractional Dehn twist coefficient $c(h)$ in some sense measures the difference between $h$ and its Thurston representative $g$. More specifically, one can consider the suspension flow of $g$ which has periodic orbit $p\lambda + q\mu$, where $\lambda=\partial S$, $\mu$ is the meridian. Then $c(h)=p/q$.
I wonder if one can define something similar for a rational open book (S,h). In this case, however, $h$ does not fix the boundary $\partial S$. When $\partial S$ is connected, in particular, $h$ restricts to a neighborhood of $\partial S$ is a rigid rotation. Some power $h^n$ of $h$ fixes $\partial S$. The fractional Dehn twist coefficient can be defined for $h^n$ as above.
On the other hand, if $g$ is the Thurston representative, it seems to me that one may still consider the suspension flow of $g$. It is not obvious to me that these two notions coincide.
Finally, are these two notions potentially useful as the ordinary FDTC in any sense? I am interested because rational open book arises from Dehn surgery naturally.
